# How to word wrap a QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt4, pyqt

I have to populate a QTreeWidget with items (or children of items) that may happen to be too long to fit in a single line, so I'm looking for a way to word wrap them.

I thought

```
myQTreeWidget.setWordWrap(True)
```

(done via QtDesigner4) would have done the job, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I don't know if it is relevant, but the tree is enveloped in a splitter frame, so the wrapping should be somehow dynamic to allow resizing of the splitter.

Any ideas? I use PyQt4, but hints in any language/binding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I successfully found a workaround: i envelope a QLabel in the WidgetItem, setting the QLabel to have word wrap capabilities.

```
item = QTreeWidgetItem()
label = QLabel('long text here')
label.setWordWrap(True)

MyTree.addTopLevelItem(item)
MyTree.setItemWidget(item, 0, label)
```

the behaviour is exactly the one desired!!

Comment: Cool solution, thanks for sharing.  Also, you might want to change "clinicalBox" to "label" in your answer.

Comment: hehe, sorry! That's what happens with naive copy&paste :)

Comment: I'm having a problem with spacing on the QLabel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007272/remove-space-from-qlabel-in-a-qtreewidget

Comment: You can also implement a custom delegate to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623036/implementing-a-delegate-for-wordwrap-in-a-qtreeview-qt-pyside-pyqt

Comment: Note that this worked for me, BUT I was getting a crash.  According to this question, you need to either set a label for the parent or keep a reference to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644304/setitemwidget-causing-crash . I opted for the keep-a-reference version: `self.label = QLabel('Long text here')`.  (I am using PySide version 1.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

`setWordWrap` just causing wrapping around word-boundaries... it will NOT force anything on to a new line.

What you are looking for is **not possible** with the default `QTreeWidget`. I suggest displaying text that is too long in an alternative way, such as mouse-over text or a separate label. TreeViews should not contain more then one line of text per item.

Comment: but if i do

    item = QTreeWidgetItem(['some text \n and some more'])

it is displayed exactly as one would expect: an item on two lines.

Comment: Real (dynamic) word-wrapping is not possible though. The only thing you might do to simulate word-wrap is write your own word-wrap function that adds newlines to the item stings based on the width of the widget, and then create a signal to call that function when the size of the widget changes.

Comment: I'm trying to envelope a QLabel or a QText-something within an item, so that then i inherit the word wrapping capabilities form the text box, whatever the one it happens to do the right job

Comment: @japs it returns the same result https://prnt.sc/11x0f6f You can see that all other rows uses 2 charecters too