# setItemWidget causing crash

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to add a `QLabel` to a `QTreeWidgetItem` but Python crashes on the `setItemWidget` call.

Any ideas why it crashes?

Here is the code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

view = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
view.show()

newItem =  QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(view)
view.setItemWidget(newItem,0,QtGui.QLabel('abc'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the label, or give it a parent:

```
    view.setItemWidget(newItem, 0, QtGui.QLabel('abc', view))
```

Comment: Good to know. I never really know which part of Qt sets the parent and which not. For example layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('abc')) is harmless.

Comment: I was declaring the widget outside the setItemWidget() and it kept crashing. Using your method it seemed a lot happier.
view.setItemWidget(newItem, 0, QtGui.QLabel('abc', view));
widget= view.itemWidget(newItem, 0)